# PHP redirecting under certain conditions

Tags: php, redirect, iframe, mysqli

I'm trying to create a chat room using an iframe to display my chat.php file where the message is posted, and when I submit it moves to the chat.php page url in the address bar. I've used the following code to attempt to redirect back to the main chat page:

```
    header( 'Location: http://127.0.0.1/projects/chatroom/' );
```

It automatically redirects the page, which is great, but now it is redirecting in the iframe, creating multiple instances of itself within the iframe. I've tried to use the followed to fix this problem, but it doesn't work, as I've tried to put it in. I've tried to research the correct syntax but I've come up with nothing.

`if( header == ( 'Location: http://127.0.0.1/projects/chatroom/chat.php') )
       {
           header( 'Location: http://127.0.0.1/projects/chatroom/' );
       }`

Comment: instead of header == do
`"http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";` == and compare it with any other string, even though  I don't like using request uri that is why I didn't post this as an answer

Comment: Well, I tried that, entering it as the way I actually got it to work:
`if( "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]" == "http://127.0.0.1/projects/chatroom/chatlog/chat.php" )
    {
        header( 'Location: http://127.0.0.1/projects/chatroom/' );
    }`
And I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

after submitting the form in the iframe instead of:

```
    header( 'Location: http://127.0.0.1/projects/chatroom/' );
```

write down:

```
    die("<script>window.top.location.href = "Location: http://127.0.0.1/projects/chatroom/";</script>");
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixes my problem of multiple Iframe instances; however, now the Iframe keeps dying within the Iframe I think from my understanding of it.